# Best practice for validating Input variables in Boolean functions

Tags: validation

At work we often use functions returning a BOOLEAN where the BOOLEAN represents a logical statement and not whether the operation of the function was successfully or not 
e.g. BOOLEAN HaseThisValueBeCountedAlready (Value)

When validating the input in this function what would be the best way proceed if invalid input was detected. Some people think to just return FALSE but in my opinion that would just hide the fact that something is wrong and the Caller might proceed doing something with the value not knowing that the answer doesn't make sense.

The function might be globally accessible so it feels a bit weird assuming the caller will validate the input.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In general, for invalid input that doesn't enable the functions to provide the service/answer, you need to raise an exception.

This way, the guy asking the "question"  to the function knows he's not "formulating" it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

if its a value that need to be read periodically , you can assign the output to a global variable ,if it valid or dont update global variable if the input is invalid , so the global variable stays with the previous valid value.

this way , each function need this value , use the global variable with 100% that is valid value.